# Error while retriving data from database mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

the following is the code in which i got error while retrieving data from database in ROR.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
      <h2> List of Organization Details</h2>

      <%= b_search_bar(um_org_data_path).html_safe %>
      </br></br>


      <%= form_tag destroy_multiple_users_path, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete all these?' } do %>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Organization Name</th>
            <th>Organization Description</th>
            <th>Office Address</th>
            <th>Office Phone Number</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>


         <% @um_org_data.each do |um_org_data| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= check_box_tag "deleted_ids[]", um_org_data.org_name%></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.org_desc%></tdc>
              <td><%= um_org_data.offc_addr%></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.offc_ph%></td>
              <td>
                <%= link_to "<i class='icon-eye-open'></i>".html_safe, "data-original-title" => "View Details", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>
              </td>
          </tr>

        </tr>
        </table>
        <%end%>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////--><h1>Listing Organization Data</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Organization Name</th>
    <th>Organization Description</th>
    <th>Office Address</th>
    <th>Office Phone Number</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @um_org_data.each do |um_org_datum| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= um_org_datum.org_name %></td>
    <td><%= um_org_datum.org_description %></td>
    <td><%= um_org_datum.offc_addr %></td>
    <td><%= um_org_datum.offc_ph %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', um_org_datum %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_um_org_datum_path(um_org_datum) %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Um org datum', new_um_org_datum_path %>
```

the above are two type of code snippets the above is the actual thing i wants to do but got following error:

```
NoMethodError in Um_org_data#index

Showing /home/wasif/RoshanERP/app/views/um_org_data/index.html.erb where line #25 raised:

undefined method `org_desc' for #<UmOrgDatum:0x007fc0e8b17000>

Extracted source (around line #25):

22:          <% @um_org_data.each do |um_org_data| %>
23:             <tr>
24:               <td><%= check_box_tag "deleted_ids[]", um_org_data.org_name%></td>
25:               <td><%= um_org_data.org_desc%></tdc>
26:               <td><%= um_org_data.offc_addr%></td>
27:               <td><%= um_org_data.offc_ph%></td>
28:               <td>
```

where are the code below comment is working fine.! thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your db schema?

Comment: My database table name is "um_org_data" and field names are org_name, org_description, offc_addr, offc_ph.......

Comment: and model name is um_org_datum.rb

Comment: its just a single table... no join with other tables and just retrieving data from single table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<%= um_org_data.org_desc %>
```

you should have

```
<%= um_org_data.org_description %>
```

as this is your column name in DB, so activerecord automatically creates `UmOrgDatum#org_description` method to fetch this column's value. It doesn't create method `UmOrgDatum#org_desc` because there is no such column in your table and that's why you get an error.

Comment: thanks... sorry i was out of mind..... dont get where i was stuck... now its worked.! Thanks You so Much!